# How to get variables values from a view to controller method and then pass these value to a modal to store in database:codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

I have following variable in my view i want to get these all in a controller and then pass to a modal to store in database:

```
$value = $parts[count($parts) - 3];
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
$user_name = $this->session->userdata('user_name'); 
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$valu =  $_POST['domain'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fast overview of CI (This is NOT meant to be copied and pasted, its just to give an idea)

Session data is available every you have loaded the session class:

```
  class ex_controller extends CI_controller{
        public $user;
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('session');
            //now we can use these methods:
             $this->user = $this->session->userdata('user_id);
         }
    }
```

Post data must be posted to the server, here is an example using a form:

```
<? echo form_open('domains/add_domain);?> <!--MUST load CI's form helper to use this-->
 <input name="domain" value="domain>
 <btn type="submit" value="ds">Submit</btn>
<? echo form_close();?>
```

Your controller you are posting to:

```
class domains extends CI_controller{
     public function __construct()
     {
         //load requirements, like example above
     }

     public function add_domain()
     {
          //I posted data to this method, it can be accessed like:
         $domain = $this->input->post('domain');  //$this->input->post('fieldname');
         //I can then update the db by loading a model (you can load it in constructor as well
         $this->load->model('example_model');
          $this->example->add_domain($domain);
      }
 }
```

Finally the model:

```
class Example_model extends CI_Model{
     public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->database();
    }

    public function add_domain($domain)
    {
        $this->db->set('column_name', $domain);
        return $this->db->insert('table');
    }
}
```

Comment: what about the other variable its work perfectly for one variable, but i have more than one variables to pass to model:
                   
                   public function save(){
                   $domain =  $this->input->post('domain'); 
                   $user_id =  $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    
                    $this->load->model('user_model');
                    $this->user_model->add_domain($domain,   $user_id);

Comment: just have the method in the model accept as many arguments has you have to pass: `public function add_domain($arg1, $arg2...)`